# I always get redirected to home page when refresh any page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context

I traveled through topics similar situation to mine, but I still not found the solution to my case.

When I implemented checking token function on `app.js` to generate code for Unauthenticated User redirect to Signin page and Authenticated User jump to Hompage.

However, after this part my SPA started getting redirect to home page from any page when refreshing/F5.

Below is my `authContext.js`:

```
export const AuthContext = createContext({
  token: null,
  userId: null,
  isLoggedIn: false,
  login: (userId, token) => {},
  logout: () => {},
});

const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState();
  const [token, setToken] = useState();

  const loginUserHandler = useCallback((userId, token) => {
    setUserId(userId);
    setToken(token);
    localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify({ userId, token }));
  }, []);

  const logoutUserHandler = useCallback(() => {
    setUserId(null);
    setToken(null);
    localStorage.removeItem("userData");
  }, []);

  const initialValues = {
    userId: userId,
    token: token,
    isLoggedIn: !!token,
    login: loginUserHandler,
    logout: logoutUserHandler,
  };

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={initialValues}>{props.children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export default AuthContextProvider;
```

And `app.js` code

```
function App() {
  const { token, login } = useContext(AuthContext);
  let routes;

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
    if (storedData && storedData.token) {
      login(storedData.userId, storedData.token);
    }
  }, [login]);

  if (token) {
    routes = (
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" exact>
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/leads-manager" exact>
              <Leads />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/phone-manager" exact>
              <Phone />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/new-notifications" exact>
            <Notification />
          </Route>
          <Redirect to="/home" exact />
        </Switch>
      </Layout>
    );
  } else {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/sign-in" exact>
          <Login />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/sign-in" />
      </Switch>
    );
  }

  return <BrowserRouter>{routes}</BrowserRouter>;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you don't initialize the `token` state from localStorage in the `AuthContextProvider` component when the component mounts. When you reload the page all React state will be lost since it exists only in memory. `token` is falsey and the `App` component renders the "unauthenticated" route/redirect. I believe what is happening is the `token` is falsey and the user is bounced to `"/sign-in"` and at the same time the `useEffect` hook in `App` pulls from local storage and authenticates the user, which updates the `userId` and `token` states. `token` is defined now and the "authenticated" routes render, and because the URL path is still `"/sign-in"` the `Redirect` to `"/home"` is rendered.

Use `useEffect` hooks to (A) persist state changes to localStorage and (B) initialize the `userId` and `token` states.

```
const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState();
  const [token, setToken] = useState();

  // Effect to initialize local state and reauthenticate
  useEffect(() => {
    const { userId, token } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData")) || {};
    if (userId) setUserId(userId);
    if (token) setToken(token);

    if (userId && token) {
      login(userId, token);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token || userId) {
      localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify({ userId, token }));
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem("userData");
    }
  }, [token, userId]);

  const loginUserHandler = useCallback((userId, token) => {
    setUserId(userId);
    setToken(token);
  }, []);

  const logoutUserHandler = useCallback(() => {
    setUserId(null);
    setToken(null);
  }, []);

  const initialValues = {
    userId: userId,
    token: token,
    isLoggedIn: !!token,
    login: loginUserHandler,
    logout: logoutUserHandler,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={initialValues}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Update the `App` component to explicitly check if the `token` is undefined when the component mounts to conditionally return early so neither the "authenticated" or "unauthenticated" routes/redirect logic are applied.

```
function App() {
  const { token } = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (token === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      {token
        ? (
          <Layout>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/leads-manager" component={Leads} />
              <Route path="/phone-manager" component={Phone} />
              <Route path="/new-notifications" component={Notification} />
              <Redirect to="/home" />
            </Switch>
          </Layout>
        )
        : (
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/sign-in" component={Login} />
            <Redirect to="/sign-in" />
          </Switch>
        )
      }
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks, your method working but I will need sometimes to test more cases. I will reports u few days later!

Comment: @J.Tran Welcome, glad to help. Please let me know if you've further questions/issues with the suggested solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed code a little bit
I added one more state to check display the `Loader.js` (mainly for preventing route redirection to hit unwanted routes)

First time runs project `hasInitVal = false` will show the `Loader.js`. After `app.js` component mount and useEffect function get executed, value of `hasInitVal` changed and `app.js` reload again to display corresponding routes base on the token values.

`autContext.js` file

```
import { createContext, useCallback, useState } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext({
  token: null,
  userId: null,
  isLoggedIn: false,
  login: (userId, token) => {},
  logout: () => {},
});

const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

  const loginUserHandler = useCallback((userId, token) => {
    setUserId(userId);
    setToken(token);
    localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify({ userId, token }));
  }, []);

  const logoutUserHandler = useCallback(() => {
    setUserId(null);
    setToken(null);
    localStorage.removeItem("userData");
  }, []);

  const initialValues = {
    userId: userId,
    token: token,
    isLoggedIn: !!token,
    login: loginUserHandler,
    logout: logoutUserHandler,
  };

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={initialValues}>{props.children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export default AuthContextProvider;
```

`app.js` file

```
function App() {
  const { token, login } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [hasInitVal, setHasInitVal] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const userToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
    if (userToken && userToken.userId && userToken.token) {
      login(userToken.userId, userToken.token);
    }
    setHasInitVal(true);
  }, [login]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {!hasInitVal && <Loader />}
      {!token && hasInitVal && (
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/sign-in" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/sign-in" />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      )}

      {token && hasInitVal && (
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path="/home"
              element={
                <Layout>
                  <TblContextProvider>
                    <Home />
                  </TblContextProvider>
                </Layout>
              }
            />

            <Route
              path="/leads-manager"
              element={
                <Layout>
                  <TblContextProvider>
                    <Leads />
                  </TblContextProvider>
                </Layout>
              }
            />

            <Route
              path="/phone-manager"
              element={
                <Layout>
                  <TblContextProvider>
                    <Phone />
                  </TblContextProvider>
                </Layout>
              }
            />

            <Route path="/new-notifications" element={<Notification />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```